# Findall <li> with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm looking to exotract the "def" part of project-data with beautifulsoup:

```
<div
   <ul
      <li class : "abc" project-data: "def">
      <li class : "abc" project-data: "ghi">
```

I've tried :

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html.parser")
data = soup.find('li', {'data-project': ''}).text
print(data)
```

Does someone has an idea how to retrieve this data ?

Comment: The html seems seriously malformed. Is it looking exactly like that? For example there are missing `=` after attribute names

Comment: My bad, here's the correct html format:
<div class="aaa">
   <ul class="bbb">
      <li class="ccc" data-project="ddd"
      <li class="ccc" data-project="eee"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your HTML is more or less like this:

```
<div>
 <ul>
     <li class = "abc" project-data= "def"></li>
     <li class = "abc" project-data= "ghi"></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Do:

```
vals = soup.find_all("li")

for val in vals:
    print(val.attrs['project-data'])
```

Output:

```
def
ghi
```

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS selector `li[project-data]`. This will find all `<li>` tags which contains attribute `project-data=`. CSS Selectors are invoked in `bs4` with methods `select()` and `select_one()`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''<div>
   <ul>
      <li class="abc" project-data="def">
      <li class="abc" project-data="ghi">'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

for li in soup.select('li[project-data]'):
    print(li['project-data'])
```

Prints:

```
def
ghi
```

More about [CSS selectors here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).